# Sharepoint 2010 custom WCF service

Tags: wcf, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to create a custom WCF service and to host it in Sharepoint 2010. I found a howto on how to do that here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521581.aspx

the problem is the attribute "BasicHttpBindingServiceMetadataExchangeEndpointAttribute" which should be in Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Services.

But I could neither find the dll file nor the attribute. On the internet there is not much information about that.

Does anybody know from where I can get this dll or does anybody have a link to a good howot or tutorial on how to create WCF services on Sharepoint?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Ya ran into that problem too. The answer is in the tutorial but I missed it.

To add a reference to Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime, which contains the service factories that are provided by SharePoint Foundation, use the Browse tab of the Add Reference box to navigate to the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime.dll file within %Windows%\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime, select the DLL, and click OK.

Then you need a using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Services;
above the attribute.
I don't have a reference to this namespace just a using statement. Also make sure you have the microsoft.sharepoint.client and microsoft.sharepoint.client.serverruntime references
I got stuck after deploying myself. Got 404 errors and couldn't add the service reference to test it. If you find a fix please email me at
mondo at shaw.ca
thanks and good luck!